# Regex - match after sequence of characters

Tags: regex, match, capturing-group

I'm trying to create a regex that matches either a 4, 5, or 6 digit number. If the first characters are zeros, only the last 4 digits should be matched or any characters greater than zero if 5 characters present, if the first number is 1-9 it can remain either 5 or 6 digits depending on the number.

Here's some example text (pretend the lines are separate instances this isn't a list in the context of usage):

```
10455   (should be)-> 10455
006995         -----> 6995
002085         -----> 2085
00000001       -----> 0001
0001           -----> 0001
106            -----> 0106
8181           -----> 8181
0093355        -----> 93355
8              -----> 0008
649402         -----> 649402
01             -----> 0001
02             -----> 0002
000000001      -----> 0001
0815           -----> 0815
```

I am solving this one step at a time starting with addressing the excessive zeros. If anyone has a solution for the whole problem that would be great, but I am mostly wondering how to match the last 4 or 5 digits after a string of 0s. Thanks

Comment: The OP asks for a matching task only. Though `106` can be matched the result of `0106` can only be achieved by an additional transformation task. Likewise the `8`/`0008`, `01`/`0001` and `02`/`0002` requirement. Does the OP just ask for the matching regex or for the necessary mapping task as well?

Comment: For now I am just looking for matching, I don't wanna ask for too much so I am trying to limit my question to the problem with 0s at the start of 00000001 or 001234

Comment: I got this working ```/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$|[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$|[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$/```, would it be a viable solution with the numbers under 4 digits aside?

Comment: If it is about the regex only, something like this ... [`/(?:^0+(\d{4,5})$)|(\d{4,6})$/`](https://regex101.com/r/gZVJxn/1/) ... is as far as one can go with squeezing all the possible and not contradicting **match**ing requirements into a single regex (actually there are two expressions separated by `|`). The rest needs additional treatment.

Comment: Regarding the provided final solution, are there any questions left?

Comment: Meanwhile there is a solution waiting which does it all ... and ... at SO it is considered to be a nice gesture from the one who got help, to provide some feedback and/or vote on answers and/or accept the answer which was the most helpful in solving the OP's problem.

Answer (score 1):

A regex which does it all, capturing  ...

- the zero trailing digits, as well as
- the exact matching digits, and in addition
- the too short digit sequences which need to be filled from left

... looks like the following one ...

[`/^0+(?<zeroTrailer>\d{4,5})$|(?<exactMatch>\d{4,6})$|(?<padLeft>\d+)$/`](https://regex101.com/r/gZVJxn/3).

The regex features named groups, thus a further validation and or transformation can be implemented more expressive like shown with the following example code ...

```js
const testData = [
//['input', 'result'],
  ['10455', '10455'],
  ['006995', '6995'],
  ['002085', '2085'],
  ['00000001', '0001'],
  ['0001', '0001'],
  ['106', '0106'],
  ['8181', '8181'],
  ['0093355', '93355'],
  ['8', '0008'],
  ['649402', '649402'],
  ['01', '0001'],
  ['02', '0002'],
  ['000000001', '0001'],
  ['0815', '0815'],
];
const regX =
  // see ... [https://regex101.com/r/gZVJxn/3]
  /^0+(?<zeroTrailer>\d{4,5})$|(?<exactMatch>\d{4,6})$|(?<padLeft>\d+)$/;

// visual test log.
console.log(
  testData.map(([str]) => {
    const {

      zeroTrailer,
      exactMatch,
      padLeft,

    } = regX.exec(str)?.groups ?? {};

    return [
      str,
      (zeroTrailer ?? exactMatch ?? padLeft?.padStart(4, 0)),
    ].join(' => ');
    
  }).join('\n')
);

// requirements test result log.
console.log(
  'did all tests pass ?..',
  testData.every(([inputValue, expectedValue]) => {
    const {

      zeroTrailer,
      exactMatch,
      padLeft,

    } = regX.exec(inputValue)?.groups ?? {};

    return (
      expectedValue ===
      (zeroTrailer ?? exactMatch ?? padLeft?.padStart(4, 0))
    );
  })
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @Riceman ... Regarding the above provided final solution, are there any questions left?